# Merging DataFrames Causing Int Value Error

Tags: pandas, merge, int

I apologize before hand as I'm new to programming, Python, and Pandas. I am trying to merge five dataframes in steps based on  datetime indexs and using an outer join. The data is water level gauging station data that I've attached in the following link: https://drive.google.com/open?id=15t7wkU0Sl17WgIS6CAgJpkWONdppdhvH . The data comes from a variety of Canadian and American water level gauging station systems and is all fairly similar except that the American data in the link has to be reduced to a datum by simply subtracting the elevation of the station. I've added the American stations into their own module to handle the processing. The merging works fine except when merging the processed American data which throws the following error:

```
ValueError: can not merge DataFrame with instance of type <type 'int'>
```

Could someone please give me some insight into this error?

I've searched the dataframes for ints and tried converting the dataframe to a string or dataframe but still have had no luck merging them.

def readNOAA():

```
noaaDFs = {}

filenames = glob.glob(r"C:\Users\Andrew\Documents\CHS\SeasonalGaugeAnalysis\Input\CO-OPS_*_wl.csv")

dataframes = [pd.read_csv(filename) for filename in filenames]


for df, filename in zip(dataframes, filenames):
    df['filename'] = os.path.basename(filename)
    df['Station ID'] = df['filename'].str[7:14]
    del df['filename']

combined_df = pd.concat(dataframes, ignore_index=True)

df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(combined_df)

df['Date Time (UTC)'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'] + ' ' + df['Time (GMT)'])

#df['Date Time (UTC)'] = df['Date Time (UTC)'].tz_localize('utc') 

df.set_index('Date Time (UTC)', inplace=True)
df.index = df.index.to_datetime().tz_localize('utc')

df['WL'] = df['Preliminary (m)'].where(df['Verified (m)'].isnull(), df['Preliminary (m)'])
df['WL'] = df['WL'].replace({'-': np.nan})
df.drop(['Date', 'Time (GMT)', 'Predicted (m)', 'Preliminary (m)', 'Verified (m)'], axis=1, inplace=True)



Station3 = df[df['Station ID'].str.match('9052030')] #Oswego, NY
#Station3['Temp Station ID'] = '13771'
Station3['WL'] = Station3['WL'].astype(float) - 74.2
Station3.rename(columns={'WL':'9052030'}, inplace=True)
del Station3['Station ID']
noaaDFs["9052030"]=9052030

hydrometDF = readHydromet()
pcwlDF = readPCWL()
noaaDF = readNOAA()

# Create 3 minute time series to merge station data to so data gaps can be identified
idx = pd.date_range('06-21-2019 20:00:00', periods=25000, freq='3 min')
ts = pd.Series(range(len(idx)), index=idx)
cts = ts.to_frame()
cts.index = cts.index.to_datetime().tz_localize('utc')
cts.drop(0, axis=1, inplace=True)

final13771 = pd.merge(hydrometDF["Station11985"], pcwlDF["station13988"], how='outer', left_index=True,right_index=True)
final13771 = pd.merge(final13771, pcwlDF["station13590"], how='outer', left_index=True,right_index=True)
final13771 = pd.merge(final13771, pcwlDF["station14400"], how='outer', left_index=True,right_index=True)
final13771 = pd.merge(final13771, noaaDF["9052030"], how='outer', left_index=True,right_index=True)
final13771 = pd.merge(final13771, cts, how='outer', left_index=True,right_index=True)
final13771.to_excel("13771.xlsx")
```

Comment: on which line you are getting this error?

Comment: sorry, just noticed I included the wrong merge in my code example but I'm getting the error on the final13771 = pd.merge(final13771, noaaDF["9052030"], how='outer', left_index=True,right_index=True) line

Comment: As per the error `noaaDF["9052030"]` is just an int, so you can't merge it with the dataframe.

Comment: Thanks very much Vishal! Just realized what I did from your comment. Dumb beginner mistake.